# how to get pre-populated result for custom google search in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-search, google-custom-search

Wanted to achieve `google` custom search result like below

**expected result (without any popup):**

[image]

But i'm getting result something like below one

[image]

**Observe the above result is not pre-populated and does not give resume tags like Indeed,LinkedIn**

When i search for `software developer resume`  then it will give me **result like below one**

[image]

**Question**: please help me to get pre-populated result like 1st image without any popup

Here is what i have tried:

```js
(function() {  
    var cx = '005502706694827175734:jh1_mjmyukc';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
```

```html
<gcse:search linktarget="_parent" resultsUrl="https://cse.google.com/cse/home?cx=008650345519931166596:ni_z2d9ca00#gsc.tab=0&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Alinkedin"></gcse:search>

// this url gives Indeed,LinkedIn related results https://cse.google.com/cse/home?cx=008650345519931166596:ni_z2d9ca00#gsc.tab=0&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Alinkedin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "two page" layout as described on these pages:
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2633315

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox